# qwtcurve doesn't draw graph

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem, recently I've installed qwt library to draw graph and was running through some simple tutorials( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l2VIooQXVc this tutorial to be exact, that I have ran into trouble ) and have met a problem. My graph won't paint. Qwt just paints coordinate system and title.The difference between my code and tutorial code, that he paints straight in main, but I do this in QMainWindow, adding plot to QLayout.
Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::PrioritizeGraphic()
{

   plot = new QwtPlot( QwtText( "Demo" ) );
   plot->setAxisScale( QwtPlot::xBottom, 0.0, 2.0 * M_PI * 10 );
   plot->setAxisScale( QwtPlot::yLeft, -3.0, 3.0 );
   int i = 0;
   double xl[200], yl[200];
   QwtPlotCurve curve( "Sine curve" );
   while( i < 100 )
   {
       for( double x = 0; x < 2.0 * M_PI * 5; x += ( M_PI / 10.0 ) )
       {
           yl[i] = sin(x);
           xl[i] = x;
           i++;
           curve.setRawSamples( ( const double* )&xl, ( const double* )&yl, i );
           curve.attach( plot );
      }
   }

   curve.setRawSamples( ( const double* )&xl, ( const double* )&yl, 100 );
   curve.attach( plot );
   plot->show();



}
```

And in the QMainWindow constructor:

```
QLayout* lay = ui->centralWidget->layout();

lay->addWidget( plot );
```

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for your code is not working is; below variables are created in the scope of function `MainWindow::PrioritizeGraphic()`:

- `double xl[200]`
- `double yl[200]`
- `QwtPlotCurve curve( "Sine curve" )`

Since they are defined in the scope of a function, they will be destroyed when function finishes. As a solution you can make them class members so they will survive as long as your `MainWindow` object is not destroyed.

The code you referenced works because variables are defined in `main()` function and `main()` function doesn't finish as long as application runs.

Also you can use `QwtPlotCurve::setSamples` instead of `QwtPlotCurve::setRawSamples`. It will make a deep copy of the data, so you can freely delete your arrays.

Comment: Yeap that's the thing, I just thought that all stuff attaches to the plot and we just need to save the plot.Thx for answer.

Comment: When you pass a pointer to an object/function, you should assume that they don't copy the object that pointer *points to* unless it's strictly mentioned in the documentation.